# Should we always declare a method as static if it does not access "this" object properties or methods

Tags: c#, oop, static

Many times I have come across a scenario where we need some helper functions defined in a class. Below is an example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private void BeautifyOrValidate(MyRequest request)
    {
        //Beautify or validate request
    }
    public void DoOperation(MyRequest request)
    {
        BeautifyOrValidate(request);
        //Do actual operation
    }
}
```

In above example "BeautifyOrValidate" can be made static. At a time many such functions can exist in a class.
I would like to know if we should always use static keyword for such methods or there are some other rules for this.

Comment: I see a possibility to [extract](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) a `MyRequestBeautifier` and `MyRequestValidator` class.

Answer (score 3):

For a private members it does not matter as much, making it static is a tiny optimization.

For public members the basic rule is that when it can be static, it should be. Just to be clear about the fact that no `MyClass` instance is involved in `BeautifyOrValidate(request)`

Comment: So if it's an optimization for private members, there's no reason not to do it right?

Comment: Never heard of such "basic rule", any chance of further clarification?

Comment: The optimization is an aside, it should not be the major decision point.

Comment: It's not an optimization consideration, it's a design consideration.  By making it static you're telling the world that it won't modify any non-static member variables within the class.

Comment: @HenkHolterman well if there are no downsides, there seems to be nothing to decide between except the 1 second it takes to type `static` :)

Comment: Mocking statics is difficult to say the least.

Comment: @MarvinSmit: that's exactly the point. Statics are not parts of interfaces nor can be easily replaced with inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

(I suppose it is a question for programmers.stackexchange...) Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2267438/2018771

As others stated, you should probably own a resharper :).
If it can be made static, it means:

- the method **does not use any instance variables**
- the method **does not call** any **other methods** that use instance variables

Then you have choices depending on the code (there's no general rule here!)

- You can **move** `BeautifyOrValidate(MyRequest request)` **logic** ***into*** `MyRequest`, if that makes sense (code is working with non-static methods of `MyRequest`). That's cool, as you have found additional functionality of `MyRequest`, and where else you should put that? 
  For me, **passing the same variable across functions is a sign of making it an instance variable** in its own class (either in the "old" one, or in a new, as I have identified a new responsibility of a new class).
- `BeautifyOrValidate(MyRequest request)` is a function that transforms MyRequest, but has a logic not associated with MyRequest or a broader usage, that **can be extracted to a static helper class**. Think of it as a toolkit for transform data of `MyRequest`.
- **you can make it static**, but if `MyClass` hasn't got any really strong connection with `MyRequest` people will be confused, and they won't know where to search for `BeautifyOrValidate(MyRequest request)` (and eventually they will write their *own version*, which they can find, resulting in inconsistent behavior, whether others find your or their code...).

My personal preference is not to write extension methods until it is really-really needed, e.g. `MyRequest` is third party code, or you *can not/must not* modify and it is `sealed`, etc. etc. Or no other projects will need that modification and the functionality is specific to your project and it clears up your code.

If you choose the first version, you can remove that parameter:

```
MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest();
myRequest.BeautifyOrValidate();
```

Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it makes no practical difference.

If you use a code analysis tool like Resharper and are obsessed with the magical zero warnings status (hey, nothing wrong with that) then you may need to make these methods static, or adjust your rules.

Alternatively, what about moving these out to a static class and making them extension methods?

```
public static class RequestUtilities
{
    public static void BeautifyOrValidate(this MyRequest request) 
    { 
        ... 
    }
}
```

This has a nice feel to it and avoids the deep moral dilemmas you currently face.

Otherwise, I think it comes down to personal preference. Resharper aside, my preference is not to make these static as this doesn't really reflect the intention I have when I deliberately make methods static.

Be assured that there's no definite answer and in the general scheme of things it probably doesn't matter in the slightest.